# MVVM How I can have different textcolor in a liestview

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

How can I change one row line color.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfChar}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="AAAA" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AAAA}"/>               
            <GridViewColumn Header="XXXX" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=XXXX}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="BBBB" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=BBBB}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

So I have got a listView with 3 column AAAA, XXXX, BBBB. If the column XXXX is equal to 1 then i want color red, if is equal to 2 then blue and if equal to 3 then green in the other case i want keep black

NB : XXXX is a string

Answer (score 0):

Create a style for all your ListViews and then use a DataTrigger to set the foreground color, i.e.:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XXXX}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XXXX}" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Note this is a very simple case and therefore one of the very rare cases where I'd say it's ok to just do this in XAML. Once you start adding any real logic then it's better to bind to a property in your view model that you create specifically for this (i.e. `public bool IsError.....`) and then have your view model update it whenever any of the other properties change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I have edited my question, just a question where do you add the code you gived me? in the main view xaml?

Comment: `<Listview.Resources>` is the resources dictionary for the `ListView` control, so add it immediately after the first line (`<ListView ItemsSource="{...etc...}">`) in the code you posted above.